# javascript read binary file

Tags: javascript, dataview

I am trying to read binary file with function in global scope:

```
 function GetDataView(file_name, callback){

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var data_view = [];

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==200 ||xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.readyState=="complete"){

              data_view = new DataView(this.response);   //DataView is not defined here
              callback(data_view);

             }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", file_name,true);

        xmlhttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";


        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

It works well in Chrome, but in Firefox i get "DataView is not defined". Strange thing is that it works if i start Firefox with doubleclicking on index.html, but fails if i open index.html in already running browser, started with "firefox.exe".

Comment: Where is DataView defined?

Comment: Thats error i get, DataView constructor is not defined for some reason. I am new to javascript, so you can check my error exactly here http://racegame.zz.mu/  (WebGL required)

Comment: omg, i just had to update firefox, DataView is supported since firefox 15, i had 12. Still dont know why it worked sometimes.